# Change location that VS Code terminal is using

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

for some reason my VS Code terminal is based in some random folder, and I have to use an extension to refer to my folder every time I use it. Any settings I can change to make the terminal refer to a different folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a folder, the terminal should open at the root of that folder. So there might be a misconfiguration somewhere.

But if you want to specify a folder:

```
// An explicit start path where the terminal will be launched, this is used as the 
// current working directory (cwd) for the shell process. This may be particularly 
// useful in workspace settings if the root directory is not a convenient cwd.
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "",
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this, but once I change it I cannot use the terminal, is this the correct usage? - "terminal.integrated.cwd": "D:\_Bot\program",

Comment: You'll need to double backslash: "D:_Bot\\program"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `code -r "Working Directory"`, to change working directory through terminal.